# How to find the integral $\int \tan (5x) \tan (3x) \tan(2x) \ dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the integral $\int \tan (5x) \tan (3x) \tan(2x) \ dx $ .

This question is posted in a maths group in Facebook. What way should we use to solve integral like this?

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-parts.html

Comment: @achillehui This pretty hint could be an answer ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $t_n = \tan(nx)$, we have
$$t_5 = \frac{t_3 + t_2}{1 - t_3t_2} \iff t_5 - t_5t_3t_2 = t_3 + t_2
\implies t_5t_3 t_2 = t_5 - t_3 - t_2$$
This leads to

$$\begin{align}\int \tan(5x)\tan(3x)\tan(2x) dx 
&= \int \left(\tan(5x) - \tan(3x) - \tan(2x) \right)dx\\ 
&= \frac12 \log\cos(2x) + \frac13\log\cos(3x) - \frac15\log\cos(5x) + \text{ const. }
\end{align}$$

Comment: Well done!  (+1)

Comment: @achille hui Nice trick! (+1)